# In MatLab I need a variable to be displayed in a loop so that I can then plot it. How do I do it?

Tags: matlab

I am running a for loop 48 times. I need the last variable to be displayed after each run in a row matrix so that I can then plot it in a graph. Can you please help?

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, you might `popen` some `gnuplot` command...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't think that is what he is looking for. MatLab is in itself a visualisation tool, much more advanced than gnuplot.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell, you are asking for something like

```
for i=1:48; x(i)=some_function_of(i); end; plot(x)
```

where some_function_of() is whatever calculation you are doing.